# c++ Ordenamiento QuickSort

Tags: c++

El ejercicio es el siguiente: Realizar un arreglo que se llene con 30 números aleatorios pares que estén entre 2 y 40 también hacer  un arreglo que se llene con 30 números aleatorios impares que estén entre 1 y 39
Posteriormente,
¿Cómo implementar el programa que deberá ordenar ambos arreglos utilizando el algoritmo de Quicksort?
Ya lo realice pero me marca un error y realmente no se cual es o si me falta algo

```
 #include <ctime>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
void intercambio(int &x,int &y){
 int aux;
aux=x;
x=y;
y=aux;
 }
void quickSort(int n[],int primero,int ultimo){
int i,j,central;
int pivote;
central=(primero+ultimo)/2;
pivote=n[central];
i=primero;
j=ultimo;
do{
    while(n[i]<pivote)i++;
    while(n[j]>pivote)j--;
    
    if(i<=j){
        intercambio(n[i],n[j]);
        i++;
        j++;
    }
}while(i<=j);

if(primero<j){
    quickSort(n,primero,j);

}
if(i< ultimo){
    quickSort(n,i,ultimo);
}
}

int main(){
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

int num, n;
cout <<"Numeros pares:" << endl;
for (int i=2;i<32;i++){
n=rand()%20*2+2;
cout << n << ",";
}
cout <<"\nNumeros impares:" << endl;
for (int i=1;i<31;i++){
num=rand()%19*2+1;
cout << num << ",";
}
quickSort(n,0,29);
cout<<"Arreglo ordenado:"<<endl;
for(int i=29;i>=0;i--);
cout<<n<<",";
}
```

Comment: En `main` no estás creando un arreglo, solo estás imprimiendo la misma variable una y otra vez. Al llamar a `quickSort`, el parámetro `n` es un entero, pero la función está declarada como que recibe un arreglo. Si conocés de antemano el tamaño del arreglo podés declarar `int n[tamaño];`, sino te recomiendo que uses `std::vector<int>` en lugar de `int[]`. Si necesitás más ayuda, por favor editá la pregunta para que refleje una duda concreta (ej: `¿Cómo implementar y usar quickSort con std::vector<>?`)

Comment: "*me marca un error*" ¿A qué te refieres con "*marca*"? ¿El código no compila? ¿Compila pero no funciona? ¿El error sale por pantalla o el programa no se comporta como esperas?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 3):

El error de código que surge al compilar es el siguiente:

```
error: conversión no válida de ‘int’ a ‘int*’
 quickSort(n,0,29);
           ^
nota:   inicializando el argumento 1 de ‘void quickSort(int*, int, int)’
 void quickSort(int n[],int primero,int ultimo){
                ~~~~^~~
```

Básicamente `n` es un entero:

```
int num, n;
//       ^ <--- 'n' es de tipo 'int'.
```

Pero la estás pasando a una función en la posición en que dicha función espera una colección de enteros (puntero a entero):

```
void quickSort(int n[],int primero,int ultimo){
                   ^ <--- 'n[]' es de tipo 'int[]' que decae a 'int *'
```

En ningún sitio estás preparando una colección de valores, sólo guardando un valor aleatorio en una variable que descartas para sobrescribirlo con otro.

Además, deberias mejorar tu indentación.